# nested object arrays in tabulator

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tabulator

I'm trying to get nested object arrays working nicely with tabulator.

This is the structure of the json data:

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test 01",
        "books": [
          {
            "number": "0254",
            "details": [
              {
                "var1": "Testdata",
                "var2": "XXX"
              }
            ],
            "detail02": [
              {
                "name": "Data 01",
                "value": "5645"
              },
              {
                "name": "Data 02",
                "value": "5125"
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

Normally I can just set the data via tabulator like this:

```
columns:[
{title:"Number", field:"id"},
{title:"Name", field:"name"},
{title:"Books Number", field:"books.number"}
],
```

But `books.number` doesnt work. Can anyone give me a hint how to deal with that?

Comment: books is array containing obj with key number

Comment: Note: This functionality is only available for nested objects and will not work with arrays.

Comment: try changing the structure of the json object

Comment: did you tried `books[0].number`

Comment: I already tried `books[0].number` but doesnt work.

Problem is that I cant alter the json data I'm getting. The structure is predefined.

Comment: if you cant alter the server side try make function to restructure it in the client after receiving the JSON  response

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is books as Array, please make books Object it will work

```js
var tabledata = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test 01",
  "books": {
    "number": "0254",
    "details": [{
      "var1": "Testdata",
      "var2": "XXX"
    }],
    "detail02": [{
        "name": "Data 01",
        "value": "5645"
      },
      {
        "name": "Data 02",
        "value": "5125"
      },
    ]
  }
}];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  layout:"fitColumns",
  columns: [{
      title: "Number",
      field: "id"
    },
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Books Number",
      field: "books.number"
    }
  ],
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.4.3/css/tabulator.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.4.3/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sadly the structure of the data I'm getting is predefined. I could rearrange it, but I would still need to be able to access all information in the array. To be more cleary on the example I would also need to access `var1 `in `details ` or data in `detail02`

Comment: There is no way to parse in the data in the way you want if it is contained in arrays, Tabulator simply isn't built like that. you will need to map the data to a format that Tabulator can understand as Jay suggests

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a different approach. Tabulator got the function to take data from a normal html table.

I'm now in the middle of populate a table with a recursive function. The problem is that the `<th>` are printed for every object and not just once. Also I couldnt manage to insert all the data from one object into a `tr`.

This is what I got at the moment:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute('id', 'example-table');
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

function printValues(obj) {
    for(var k in obj) {
        if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            th.textContent = Object.keys(obj[k]);
            tr.appendChild(th);
            printValues(obj[k]);
        } else {
            var data_row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var tabCell = data_row.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.textContent = obj[k];
        }
    }
};
printValues(json);

var divContainer = document.getElementById("table-holder");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);
```